# Is this a valid proof of "A matrix A is not invertible iff 0 is an eigenvalue of A"?

Tags: proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

**Problem:** A matrix $A$ is not invertible iff $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

[My attempt:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0BCq.jpg)

Suppose $\det(A)=0$ ($A$ is not invertible).

Then $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ iff $\lambda =0$.

$\therefore A$ is not invertible iff $\lambda = 0$.

I was wondering if I'm using valid logical induction steps to prove this.

Comment: You can typeset math on this site instead of showing pictures of handwriting.  Please do.

Comment: Your proof is not correct because $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ is not sufficient to conclude that $\lambda = 0$. In particular, there are many singular matrices that have non-zero eigenvalues. The statement that you need to prove is that they must have at least one zero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid as you wrote it, but rearranging the same idea could make it correct.

You wrote "$\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ iff $\lambda =0$".  That is not true in general, and is equivalent to the statement that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$.  You conclude "$A$ is not invertible iff $\lambda = 0$," which is not a clear statement as you haven't quantified $\lambda$.

However, it is true that $A$ is not invertible if and only if $\det(A) = 0$ if and only if $\det(A-0 I)=0$ if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue for $A$.  Therefore, $A$ is not invertible if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue for $A$.  That is valid as long as you are allowed to cite theorems that give you each of the equivalencies above.

Alternatively, perhaps you have a theorem that tells you that a matrix is invertible if and only if its nullspace is trivial.  Having nontrivial nullspace is equivalent to having $0$ as an eigenvalue, directly for the definitions of what those words mean: both mean there exists $v \neq 0$ such that $Av=0$.